# Retrieving text from a ListView item with OnContextItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu

I've a ListView with a 'classic' context menu with delete and similar options. Since I'm deleting from a SharedPreferences object, I need to retrieve the key, which is the text set into ListView's items.

I've tried the following code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        AdapterContextMenuInfo saved = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById((int) saved.id);

        Log.d("DEBUG:", "before key");
        String key = view.getText().toString();
        Log.d("DEBUG:", "after...");

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.conmenu_delete:
                return true;

            case R.id.conmenu_copy:
                return true;

            case R.id.conmenu_send:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

But, unfortunately, it crashes while trying to retrieve the text from the View, as I know from logs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have already correctly casted the `AdapterContextMenuInfo`.
From there, you can get the targetView which you can cast again into the widget. I guess it's a `TextView` in your case. On that `TextView` you can call the simple `getText()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
           String key = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

           switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.conmenu_delete:
                    return true;

                case R.id.conmenu_copy:
                    return true;

                case R.id.conmenu_send:
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
          }
}
```

If your list is populated with custom objects, you obviously have to cast it to the respective type, for example:

```
Person person = (Person) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
String key = person.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    Object obj = getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    String title = obj.toString();



}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please edit your answer to add some explanation.